# Conversion of Oracle bulk collect & loop iteration into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Currently, I have code in Oracle which is basically

```
select ... bulk collect into collection c1

select ... bulk collect into collection c2

for ind_i in 1..c1.count
loop

    for ind_j in 1..c2.count
    loop
        if (c1(ind_i).column_name = c2(ind_j).column_name)
        then
            do something
        end if;
    end loop

end loop
```

How do I effectively convert this code skeleton in a SQL Server stored procedure in the most efficient way?

I am just looking for an idea of where to start the conversion.

Comment: If you want efficiency then avoid loops. Database systems like Oracle and SQL Server are set-based systems so work best with joins and applies. Avoid using loops because they are RBAR - Row By Agonizing Row.

Answer (score 0):

A scrict equivalent will be :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DO_SOMETHING ...
...
GO

select ... INTO #c1 FROM ...;
select ... INTO #c2 FROM ...;

DECLARE @SQL_DYNAMIC NVARCHAR(max) = N'';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC DO_SOMETHING ...;'
FROM   #c1
       CROSS JOIN #c2;

EXEC (@SQL);
```